# Can't open project in Visual Studio 2013 Express - Framework issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I have a program I've been making in VB for my company through Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop and have not worked on it in a couple of months. When I try to open it, I get the following error:

"The VB project "WindowsApplication1" is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=4.5" which is not installed on this machine."

http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6001/DGAfuk.png

I have all of the .NET frameworks installed including all developer and service packs (even language packs). I uninstalled all .NET frameworks and re-installed each of them without any resolution.

I tried to re-install Visual Studio and even tried changing the Framework (one of the options I have) but I cannot view any code or open designer view if I do so. (http://imageshack.com/a/img633/2109/OJaXbr.png)

The strange thing is this computer is the same one I have been developing this application on for months, so I'm not sure what happened over the last 60 days since I launched it.

Does anyone have any clues as to how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: So what happens when you make a new project or start a different project.you can always see the code from the files in the project folder.I don't know how big the project is but you could always copy the code to a new project.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try to create a new project. (http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9986/QtHWEu.png)

Comment: How long is you're path to the project file?"It must be les then 256 Character.one other thing do you maybe have a publised project that you can instal or have instaled.try and run it.if it works I would say it can't be your computer.mybe some reference prob lem.

Comment: I don't think the project file is too long as it opened from the same location before and I'm also getting this same error when I try to create a brand new project.

Comment: I did more research and just wanted to see if the path issue was the cause, and it turns out to be it. I first repaired Visual Studio and that cleared some errors. However, copying the folder with the project to C: and re-opening resolved it. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The path to your project must be Les then 256 Character.
That can be the reason of it.

Make sure the path is short "Copy the project to your c drive "C:\ProjectFolder"  and try again".